# I would like to to generate random values in C

Tags: c, random

I would like to ask about random values in C.

My C program has coding as below.

```
int random_a( int current_s,int r[num_s][num_a])
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
    if(r[current_s][i] > -1) break;
  }
  return i;
}
```

For example condition

```
r[current_s][0] and r[current_s][2] > -1
```

If I run my program, answer have only `i = 0`. But I would like to get random answer that is 0 and 2 (1 and 3 not included because `r[current_s][1]` and `r[current_s][3] = -1`).

As my plan, I would like to get a random value between 0 and 3 using `(rand()%4)`; if `(r[current_s][i] > -1)` is correct I will return that value. But if `(r[current_s][i] = -1)` generate a random number again until `r[current_s][i] > -1` then return value.

What should I do?

Comment: if you're on linux you can use [`random`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html) or if you're on windows you can use [`CryptGenRandom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I would caution against using `rand` as it's implementation dependent and a quick look at sources shows it's a very poor random.

Comment: `(rand() %4)` or the equivalent `(rand() & 3)` are probably fine. So what's the question?

Comment: this is question

I would like to get a random value between 0 and 3 using (rand()%4); if (r[current_s][i] > -1) is correct I will return that value. But if (r[current_s][i] = -1) generate a random number again until r[current_s][i] > -1 then return value.

Comment: http://programmingconsole.blogspot.in/2013/11/a-better-and-different-way-to-generate.html check this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that current_s is the row number of your matrix which contains the values -1 or greater, you can use this code :

```
int random_a(int current_a, int r[num_s][num_a])
{
 if (current_a>num_s) return 0;        //checking condition as current_a changes below
 int i;
 for (i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
    if(r[current_s][i] > -1) return i;
    else if (r[current_s][i] && i==3) return (random_a(current_a+1,r[num_s][num_a])
    else i++;
 }
}
```

here you can change current_a based on your need.